# Add SEO using WP Rest API Request C#

Tags: c#, wordpress, seo

I'm using `WP Rest API v2` to post on Wordpress and `All In One SEO Pack` for **SEO**, but I don't know what parameters should I give to add *meta title*, *meta description* and *meta tags*. I have the following code :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Website + "wp-json/wp/v2/posts/");
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
request.Method = "POST";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

var postData = "title=" + Title +
                   "&content=" + Content + // HTML Code
                   "&status=publish" +
                   "&date=" + TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var json = JObject.Parse("{" + JObject.Parse(responseString)["guid"].First + "}");
    LOG.Text = "Post posted at " + json["rendered"].ToString();
    list.Add(json["rendered"].ToString());
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Comment: What I see that you code is simillar to [Post on WordPress using WP REST API C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458678/post-on-wordpress-using-wp-rest-api-c-sharp) question but one has given any solution. I'm not a C# guy but if you need any help in php I can able to help you. and _All In One SEO Pack_ use following post_meta to save meta tags:: `_aioseop_title` for meta title, `_aioseop_description` for meta description and `_aioseop_keywords` for Meta Keyword. hope this helps you.

Comment: @RaunakGupta It's similar because it's my question (from another account) ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is build on PHP. So the WP REST API plugin is also written in PHP.
As you mentioned you use the WordPress REST api v2.
Let me start by sharing the location of the code: [WordPress REST api v2](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API)

As you can see this WP REST API does not include any SEO stuff.

Now you also installed the 'all-in-one-seo-pack' plugin. The [free version](https://github.com/wp-plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack) does not include a build-in API. You can upgrade to [Pro Version](https://semperplugins.com/all-in-one-seo-pack-pro-version/) of the 'all-in-one-seo-pack' which has a build-in API.

Or you could extend the [WordPress REST api v2](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) yourself by adding additional endpoints. And then write the PHP code yourself to manage your SEO plugin through REST API.

It is not so dificult -> as Raunak Gupta already told you: these are the fields used in the 'all-in-one-seo-pack'. Extend the REST API with additional endpoints to configure them. Then call your endpoint from C# code.

```
<wpml-config>
    <custom-fields>
        <custom-field action="translate">_aioseop_title</custom-field>
        <custom-field action="translate">_aioseop_description</custom-field>
        <custom-field action="translate">_aioseop_keywords</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
    <admin-texts>
        <key name="aioseop_options">
            <key name="aiosp_home_title" />
            <key name="aiosp_home_description" />
            <key name="aiosp_home_keywords" />
            <key name="aiosp_post_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_page_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_category_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_archive_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_tag_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_search_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_description_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_404_title_format" />
            <key name="aiosp_paged_format" />
        </key>
    </admin-texts>    
</wpml-config>
```

Take a look at the code in the free version. Use this code to get inspired in writing your own code. WordPress wants you to extend functionality. Contribute to the community!

```
if ( !function_exists( 'aioseop_ajax_save_meta' ) ) {
    function aioseop_ajax_save_meta() {
        if ( !empty( $_POST['_inline_edit'] ) && ( $_POST['_inline_edit'] != 'undefined' ) )
            check_ajax_referer( 'inlineeditnonce', '_inline_edit' );
        $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );
        $new_meta = strip_tags( $_POST['new_meta'] );
        $target = $_POST['target_meta'];
        check_ajax_referer( 'aioseop_meta_' . $target . '_' . $post_id, '_nonce' );
        $result = '';
        if ( in_array( $target, Array( 'title', 'description', 'keywords' ) ) && current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_aioseop_' . $target, esc_attr( $new_meta ) );
            $result = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_aioseop_' . $target, true );
        } else {
            die();
        }
        if( $result != '' ): 
            $label = "<label id='aioseop_label_{$target}_{$post_id}'><span style='width: 20px;display: inline-block;'></span>" . $result . '</label>';  
        else: 
            $label = "<label id='aioseop_label_{$target}_{$post_id}'></label><span style='width: 20px;display: inline-block;'></span><strong><i>" . __( 'No', 'all-in-one-seo-pack' ) . ' ' . $target . '</i></strong>';
        endif;
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce( "aioseop_meta_{$target}_{$post_id}" );
        $output = '<a id="' . $target . 'editlink' . $post_id . '" class="aioseop_edit_link" href="javascript:void(0);"'
            . 'onclick=\'aioseop_ajax_edit_meta_form(' . $post_id . ', "' . $target . '", "' . $nonce . '");return false;\' title="' . __('Edit') . '">'
            . '<img class="aioseop_edit_button" id="aioseop_edit_id" src="' . AIOSEOP_PLUGIN_IMAGES_URL . '/cog_edit.png" /></a> ' . $label;
        die( "jQuery('div#aioseop_" . $target . "_" . $post_id . "').fadeOut('fast', function() { var my_label = " . json_encode( $output ) . ";
              jQuery('div#aioseop_" . $target . "_" . $post_id . "').html(my_label).fadeIn('fast');
        });" );
    }
}
```

Comment: As I see: they ask $57 annual fee to use the pro edition. And you can only use it on 1 website. If you can tell me in detail what exact functionality you want, I might build it for you. Maybe more people need this functionality and I could charge them $$$.

Comment: As all the SEO stuff are stored in `post_meta` field it can be modified by WP REST API, Pro version of plugin is not needed. and if Plugin setting needs to be alter they are saved in wp_options table so that can also be changed through API (I guess.).